# Run multiple webpages in a single webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I've a homepage called homepage.html and when I click the "About" part, instead of going to another page, about.html, is it possible to render the about.html in homepage.html? Basically take off all the homepage.html and it becomes about.html.

I was thinking of using JavaScript where if you click "About", it would do `.remove` to remove all the elements of the homepage.html and then use `.createElement` to create the elements for "About". However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach to this. What's a good to do this?

Reason I'm doing is I'm making a game and I don't want to go to different pages when I click "Start", "Single Player", etc. and I just want to stay on the same page.

Sorry if it sounds confusing, let me know if you need any clarification.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are talking about Single Page Applications.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify things (adding / removing content) I would suggest you use AngularJS as the framework, as it's much easier than creating all the functions you need from scratch.

Comment: Beyond that, check out the yeoman angular.ja generator.  It's awesome. https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to load data of `about.html`,and then use `document.body.innerHTML` to change the page elements.

Here is a simple example,use jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'about.html',
    dataType:"text",
    type:"get",
    success:function(data){
        document.body.innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need a single page application. Javascript will do just fine. Especially if its a game you must customise the user interface 100%. No page hopping.

Create a main wrapper.
Create separate pages within the main wrapper to be displayed or generated on button click. No problem with using javascript at all.

You can also use ajax calls

Comment: Just wondering do you know any good tutorials for using JS to do this?

Comment: Here you learn to use Marionette and Backbone: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698645/A-Beginners-Guide-for-Creating-Single-Page-Applica  but simple javascript will suffice. Thinking logically all you need to do is hide and show elements